# Popup Window in Android with buttons and text fields

Tags: android, button, textfield, popupwindow

Want to know what is wrong with my code. It works fine for popup window to display simple text, but when I try to add complex things like two buttons and three edit fields just don't work. My layout is in requestPane linear layout and when I implement something like setContentView(layoutRequestPane) it blocks and exit app.
How can I show in pop up window several things like active buttons and active fields?

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

PopupWindow popUp;
LinearLayout layout;
TextView tv;
EditText textEdit;
LayoutParams params;
LinearLayout mainLayout, layoutRequestPane;
Button but;
boolean click = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    popUp = new PopupWindow(this);
    layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layoutRequestPane=new LinearLayout(this);
    mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    tv = new TextView(this);
    textEdit=new EditText(this);
    but = new Button(this);
    but.setText("Click Me");

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (click) {
                popUp.showAtLocation(mainLayout, Gravity.BOTTOM, 200, 50);
                popUp.update(0, 50, 900, 80); 
                click = false;
            } else {
                popUp.dismiss();
                click = true;
            }
        }

    });

    params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutRequestPane=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.requestPaneLayout);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    tv.setText("Hi this is a sample text for popup window");
    textEdit.getText();
    layout.addView(tv, params);
    popUp.setContentView(layout);
    // popUp.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.BOTTOM, 10, 10);
    mainLayout.addView(but, params);
    setContentView(mainLayout);


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're a beginner with Android (if not - i apologize), so I'd suggest a couple of things:

1 - having a good look at some tutorials about layouts and activities etc.

2 - work with xml to build your first UIs. when you have a good idea of how it works, then you can start creating/handling layouts and views programmatically

besides - at first sight :

1 - you overwrite layoutRequestPane by (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.requestPaneLayout) - make sure your layout is not null, and indeed what you expect it to be.

2 - you call setContentView twice. 
Lots of needless stuff going on. Try to put some order in there.

Comment: Tangerine,Thanks for a response. I am a beginner, that's true, but I got advice from friend to start with some specific project, take some similar code from web and try to adapt it. He said it should be the best way to learn. Not much usage from reading books and writing book examples.

Comment: good tutorials will always include code which will help you. Have a look at Vogella, for instance. 
Besides - as i said, work with xmls to build your first UIs. Here you're trying to inflate and add them programatically, which is less straightforward and - imo - not ideal when writing your first app.

Comment: Excellent site Tangerine, thanx... Hope that will find what I need.